# Restoring Apache Derby Database

Tags: netbeans, derby

I use Netbeans to develop a project with JSF, JPA and Java database. I can make a back up online by right clicking the database connections under services and excuting CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_BACKUP_DATABASE('c:/tem/2005-06-01') command. But how can I restore or create a database from that backup.

Several articles state that to use jdbc:derby:sample;restoreFrom=c:\mybackups\sample in the  in the boot time connection URL. What is boot time connection? I tried to use it as the connection string in Netbeans new connection dialog, but that was not successful.
Please tell me how can I restore the backup.

Answer (score 0):

There is a wealth of information about backing up and restoring Derby databases here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/adminguide/cadminhubbkup98797.html

If you're not comfortable using Derby outside of the Netbeans environment, start here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/getstart/

Comment: I referred to the previous link and in fact I have listed exact wording. "use jdbc:derby:sample;restoreFrom=c:\mybackups\sample in the in the boot time connection URL". What is boot time connection URL and how can I do it?

Comment: Sounds like the second link will be more helpful to you initially. Then later you can return to the first link and it will make more sense.